# Getting innerHTML from an [object, HTMLUnknownElement] with JavaScript (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I'm writing a script which finds elements with a tagName of `ui`, and prints to the console the content inside of the tags:

`<ui>CONTENT_HERE</ui>`

I am using the following code to perform this action.

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('ui');

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ui') {
        console.log(e[i].innerHTML());
    }
}
```

For this code, I am given the error:

```
e[i].innerHTML is not a function(...)
```

On printing out `e[i]` on its own, I am given `<ui>CONTENT_HERE</ui>` as the output.

What could I do to take the content from inside of the tags and print it to the screen?

Note - I have tried using `.html()` and `.value()` also.

NO JQuery Please. Thanks.

Comment: innerHTML is a property not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the parenthesis to access the property.

```
console.log(e[i].innerHTML);
//                       ^^
```

```js
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('ui');

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ui') {
        console.log(e[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

```html
<ui>CONTENT_HERE</ui>
```